# Java Tournament Schedule recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a homework assignment for my Java class and I am stuck on how to set up the recursion (required) to make it work.  We must prompt the user for a number of 'n' competitors (assume it must be a power of 2, we are not required to check for valid user input).  Each team must play every other team only once.  The output for n=8 should be:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
2  1  4  3  6  5  8  7
3  4  1  2  7  8  5  6
4  3  2  1  8  7  6  5
5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4
6  5  8  7  2  1  4  3
7  8  5  6  3  4  1  2
8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

The only parameter I am allowed to pass to the method is 'int n'.  So if there are 16 teams (i.e. n=16), then the second call would pass 8, then pass 4, then 2, and eventually 1.

So, based on this, I recognize that every other line just flips each pair of numbers.  So for 2^0, there is only one team.  For 2^1, it is:

```
1  2
2  1
```

For 2^2, it is 4 teams, but teams 3 and 4 have the same recursion as teams 1 and 2.  Then, you swap them so 3 and 4 come before 1 and 2 and then you swap the individual pairs again:

```
1  2  3  4
2  1  4  3
3  4  1  2
4  3  2  1
```

So you can basically split the diagram in to 4 equal corners, and each opposite corner equals each other.

I have gone through a number of variations in my code over the last couple of days, but here is where I am right now.  This is actually a step backwards from where I was, but i was originally trying to pass a start row and a start col, but I was informed that I shouldn't do that, and just pass n recursively.

```
class MyArray {
    final int MAXROW = 32, MAXCOL = 32;
    int A[][]; //reference variable
    int nR, nC; //number of integers in A, <= MAXSIZE

//constructor
MyArray() {
    A = new int[MAXROW] [MAXCOL];
    nR = nC = 0;
}

void schedule(int n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            schedule(n/2);
            for (int r = 0; r < n/2; r++)
                for (int c = 0; c < n/2; c++) {
                    A[r+n][c] = A[r][c+n];
                    A[r+n][c+n] = A[r][c];
                 }
        }
    }
void printA() {
    printA(nC-1)
}

void printA(int n) {
    if (n >= 0) {
        printA(n-1);
        for (int c = 0; c < nC; c++)
            System.out.printf("%3d", (A[n][c]));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: "*The only parameter I am allowed to pass to the method is 'int n'.*" does this method need to be recursive one, or lets say that scenario `solve(n){return recursiveMethod(x,y,z);}` is allowed?

Comment: I will give you a hint: this problem is similar to permutation but instead working with strings and characters you are working with numbers

Comment: @Shang This problem is solved with a recursive function ....

Comment: My professor finally emailed me back and told me that the most efficient and preferred way is to do a recursive call of schedule(int n) and each time you pass 'n' you divide by 2.  I have a working solution now, but it calls the recursive method twice and he made it obvious in my class tonight that he will take points off even though it works and provides the correct results.  I will also add my current answer below.

Comment: @Pshemo I am only allowed to use 1 parameter for the solve.  And I am only allowed to call it once from within the method.  See my answer below to see it working with 2 calls inside the method instead of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  Here is the code for the schedule method, nice and short and sweet, basically, top left values + (n/2) = top right and bottom left values.  Bottom right values = top left values.

```
void schedule(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        schedule(n/2);
        if (n == 1)
            A[0][0] = 1;
        else {
            for (int r = 0; r < n/2; r++)
                for (int c = 0; c < n/2; c++) {
                    A[r][c+(n/2)] = A[r][c] + (n/2);
                    A[r+(n/2)][c] = A[r][c] + (n/2);
                    A[r+(n/2)][c+(n/2)] = A[r][c];
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: much better , even if I use the recursive paradigm I prefer not to use loops ..... however I like your solution

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM.Thanks Jose.  It only took me like 4 days to boil it down to this.  My original answer was a lot more elaborate, but the whole single recursive call in the code and only passing 1 parameter in the recursion was just really confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

I could not fix your code ..... my solution:

[image: recursive]

```
public class MyArray {

    final int MAXROW = 32, MAXCOL = 32;
    int A[][]; //reference variable

    MyArray() {
        A = new int[MAXROW][MAXCOL];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyArray m = new MyArray();
        int n = 8;
        m.mySchedule(n);
        m.printA(n);
    }

    void mySchedule(int n) {
        mySchedule(n, 0, 0, n);
    }

    void mySchedule(int n, int row, int col, int carry) {
        if (n == 1) {
            A[row][col] = carry; //Trivial Case
        } else {
            //divide the problem into 4 subproblems
            int k = n / 2;
            mySchedule(k, row, col, carry - k);
            mySchedule(k, row, col + k, carry);
            mySchedule(k, row + k, col, carry);
            mySchedule(k, row + k, col + k, carry - k);
        }
    }

    void printA(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current version of the code.  My professor still says it can be more efficient by removing the 2nd recursive call.  I have included all of my comments so I remembered what each thing actually did.

```
class MySchedule {
    final int MAXSIZE = 32;
    int A[][]; //reference variable
    int max; //number of integers in A, <= MAXSIZE
    int row = 1; //keeps track of rows during recursion, row 0 set during user input

    //constructor
    MySchedule() {
        A = new int[MAXSIZE] [MAXSIZE];
        max = 0;
    }

    /*
    if teams = 4, then movements per row are: 2^0, 2^1, 2^0
    if teams = 8: 2^0, 2^1, 2^0, 2^2, 2^0, 2^1, 2^0
    (n/2) gives us the correct power to calculate movements
    for each value of n, we move n places in either direction
    for loop iterates ever 2*n
    outer loop is for each iteration
    inner loops are each number of movements for each iteration
    */
    void schedule(int n) {
        if (n >= 1) {
            schedule(n/2);
            //start at column 0 for each row
            int col = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i += (2*n)) {
                //current position uses value from previous n rows/columns.
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    A[row][col+j] = A[row-n][col+j+n];
                for (int j = n; j < n*2; j++)
                    A[row][col+j] = A[row-n][col+j-n];
                col += 2*n;
            }
            row++;
            if (n > 1)
                schedule(n/2);
        }
    }

    void printA() {
        //print header, then print team schedule
        System.out.printf("%4s", "day");
        System.out.printf("%12s", "teams");
        System.out.println();
        printA(max-1);
    }

    void printA(int n) {
        if (n >= 0) {
            printA(n-1);
            //n=0 is the row to list the teams.  
            //Following rows indicate which team they play on which day
            if (n == 0)
                System.out.printf("%4s", "");
            if (n >= 1)
                System.out.printf("%4s", "D"+n);
            for (int c = 0; c < max; c++)
                System.out.printf("%3d", (A[n][c]));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

public class Hw10 {
    //determine if n is a 2's power
    static boolean isPow(int n) {
        while (n > 1) {
            if (n%2 != 0)
                return false;
            n = n / 2;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int teams;

        //prompt user input for teams and print schedule
        do {
            System.out.print("How many teams (0 to exit): ");
            teams = in.nextInt();
            //check to make sure user input is a power of 2.
            do {
                if (isPow(teams) == false) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, must be a power of 2.");
                    System.out.print("How many teams (0 to exit): ");
                    teams = in.nextInt();
                }
            } while (isPow(teams) == false);

            //initialize array to avoid out of bounds errors on repeat tries
            MySchedule sched = new MySchedule();

            //initialize first row of array with number of teams
            for (int i = 0; i < teams; i++)
                sched.A[0][i] = i+1;
            sched.max = teams;

            sched.schedule(teams/2);
            sched.printA();
            System.out.println();
        } while (teams > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think "initialize first row of array with number of teams" should be in the constructor of `MySchedule` ...... `for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++) A[0][i] = i+1;`